# Tika AutoDetectParser is consuming BufferedInputStream of zip files

Tags: apache, zip, inputstream, apache-tika, bufferedinputstream

I am using Apache Tika to determine the MIME types of files. The AutoDetectParser seems to be consuming (resulting in a 0 byte file) the BufferedInputStream I pass as a parameter to AutoDetectParser.detect(). However, it only does this to zip files. All other file types have I have tested are unaffected.

```
public static String determineMimeType(InputStream stream, String filename) throws ParseXmlStreamException {

        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        Detector detector = parser.getDetector();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

        TikaInputStream tikaInputStream = TikaInputStream.get(stream);
        metadata.add(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, filename);
        try {
            MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(tikaInputStream,  metadata);
            return mediaType.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("Trouble detecting MIME type", e);
            throw new ParseXmlStreamException("Trouble detecting MIME type", e);
        }
    }
```

The AutoDetectParser also still correctly detects the MIME type of the zip file, but I need it to not result in a 0 byte file. I need a fix and have no idea what to try or where to look.

Comment: Use a `TikaInputStream` instead?

Comment: I do use a TikaInputStream. I believe that Tika tries to identify the underlying file type that has been zipped. I wish I could just get it to detect the application/zip MIME type without it trying to do other stuff.

Comment: Tika is having to read the whole file to check if it is really just a zip, or actually something else inside a zip (eg `docx`). Make sure you then use the `TikaInputStream` to do any subsequent reads as that will be resettable